# Обрезать углы border CSS

Tags: html, css3

[image: Как обрезать углы у border на css?]

Каким методом можно обрезать углы у border на css. Или лучше через canvas, но все же мне кажется что бы без заморочек делать каждую отдельную на canvase, лучше на css??И кстати задний фон меняющийся, вставкой псевдоэлемента треугольника не катит.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px solid #f00;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f00;
  transform-origin: 50% 100% 0;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.wrapper::before,
.wrapper::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 27px;
}

.wrapper::before {
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -2px;
  border-left: 2px solid #f00;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f00;
}

.wrapper::after {
  right: -15px;
  top: -2px;
  border-top: 2px solid #f00;
  border-right: 2px solid #f00;
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  transform: 50% 50% 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.left {
  top: 3px;
  left: -11px;
  border-left: 2px solid #f00;
}

.right {
  bottom: 3px;
  right: -11px;
  border-right: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">ГЛАВНАЯ
  <div class="left corner"></div>
  <div class="right corner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Писал же, что присутствует задний фон, наложить треугольники из псевдоэлементов не то..В общем решил сделать и отрисовать и на svg, так как лучше выхода не вижу

Comment: @КостяАбрамкин во-первых: там нет треугольников из псевдоэлементов, во-вторых: в чем проблема изменить фон в моем примере?

Comment: да спасибо, недопонял

Answer (score 0):

Привет, ты можешь это сделать через css. Используя border-radius можно задавть уровень скругления каждого угла отдельно.

```
border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
```

Что эквивалентно

```
border-top-left-radius:30px;
border-top-right-radius:0;
border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0;
```

Пример https://codepen.io/whereismymind7/pen/XRXwwK

Документация https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: border-radius не подойдет, посмотрите изображение

Comment: ну это же не то совсем..border-radius отпало же сразу

Comment: @soledar10, да, я не заметил что углы острые, в таком случае есть вариант описаный [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059597/slanted-corner-on-css-box), вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/mdQzH/)

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(4, 34, 66, 1) 0%, rgba(11, 93, 181, 1) 100%);
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  color: #A6B0BB;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:before,
.btn:after,
.btn>span:nth-of-type(1):before,
.btn>span:nth-of-type(1):after,
.btn>span:nth-of-type(2):before,
.btn>span:nth-of-type(2):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  height: 2px;
}

.btn:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
}

.btn:after {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.btn>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn>span:nth-of-type(1):before,
.btn>span:nth-of-type(1):after {
  height: calc(100% - 15px);
  width: 2px;
}

.btn>span:nth-of-type(1):before {
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
}

.btn>span:nth-of-type(1):after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.btn>span:nth-of-type(2):before,
.btn>span:nth-of-type(2):after {
  height: 22px;
  width: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .btn>span:nth-of-type(2):before,
  .btn>span:nth-of-type(2):after {
    width: 2.5px;
  }
}

.btn>span:nth-of-type(2):before {
  top: -3px;
  left: 7px;
}

.btn>span:nth-of-type(2):after {
  bottom: -3px;
  right: 7px;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after,
.btn:hover>span:nth-of-type(1):before,
.btn:hover>span:nth-of-type(1):after,
.btn:hover>span:nth-of-type(2):before,
.btn:hover>span:nth-of-type(2):after {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <span></span><span></span>Button
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background: #fff;
}

.btn {
   position: relative;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 13px;
   width: 89px;
   min-height: 28px;
   padding: 5px 0px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   font-family: "Micra Normal";
   text-align: center;
   background-color: rgba(24, 27, 38, 0.8);
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 2px;
   border: 1px solid #0f3d5b;
   clip-path: polygon(
      0% 36%,
      /* верхняя левая */ 13% 0%,
      /* верхняя левая */ 100% 0%,
      /* верхняя правая */ 100% 0%,
      /* верхняя правая */ 100% 65%,
      /* нижняя правая */ 87.5% 100%,
      /* нижняя правая */ 0% 100%,
      /* нижняя левая */ 0% 100% /* нижняя левая */
   );
}

.btn:before,
.btn:after,
.btn > span:nth-of-type(2):before,
.btn > span:nth-of-type(2):after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   background: #0f3d5b;
}

.btn:before,
.btn:after {
   width: calc(100% - 12px);
   height: 1px;
   display: none;
}

.btn:before {
   top: 0;
   left: 12px;
   position: absolute;
}

.btn:after {
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.btn > span {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.btn > span:nth-of-type(2):before {
   height: 26px;
   width: 1px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(54deg);
   transform: rotate(49deg);
}

.btn > span:nth-of-type(2):after {
   height: 26px;
   width: 1px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(49deg);
}

.btn > span:nth-of-type(2):before {
   top: -6.3px;
   left: 1.8px;
}

.btn > span:nth-of-type(2):after {
   bottom: -6.3px;
   right: 1.8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="btn">
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         play
      </a>
   </div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]